# Error using Torch RNN

Tags: python-2.7, lua, torch, luarocks

I'm following the instructions on github.com/jcjohnson/torch-rnn and have it working until the training section. When I use `th train.lua -input_h5 my_data.h5 -input_json my_data.json`I get the error `Error: unable to locate HDF5 header file at /usr/local/Cellar/hdf5/1.10.0-patch1/include;/usr/include;/usr/local/opt/szip/include/hdf5.h`

I'm new to luarocks and torch, so I'm not sure what's wrong. I installed torch-hd5f. Any advice would be very much appreciated.

Comment: did you try looking at these issues: https://github.com/jcjohnson/torch-rnn/issues/121 and https://github.com/jcjohnson/torch-rnn/issues/170?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that the header file exists and that you have the correct path.

If the header file is missing you skipped the preprocess step. If the header file exists it's likely in your data directory and not in the same directory as the sample.lua code:
th train.lua -input_h5 **data/**my_data.h5 -input_json **data/**my_data.json